# ArrayList return empty value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have one problem in code regarding Arraylist. I have two methods one method works with server to get data and inside this method i'm adding data to ArrayList. Second method is getter that will return Arraylist. But when I display data with using Log.d()  inside first method ArrayList has data. But when i try call second method ArrayList is empty. Help me!!!  Thank you in advance!!!
Below shows piece of code first method that will fetch data from server
try {

```
            JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); ++i)
            {
                ordersLists.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                ordersLists.setMain_cat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("main_cat"));
                ordersLists.setSub_cat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sub_cat"));
                ordersLists.setDate(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"));
                ordersLists.setPrice(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("price"));
                ordersLists.setComment(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("comment"));
                ordersLists.setCity(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("city"));
                arrayList.add(ordersLists);
            }
```

Second method is getter.

```
 public ArrayList<OrdersLists> getArrayList()
{
 
     return  arrayList;
}
```

Comment: This is unclear

Comment: In each iteration you are adding to `arrayList` reference to *same instance of `ordersLists`*. This means that when you modify that object it will be visible via each reference ("element") of arraylist. You prabably want to create in each iteration `new` instance for `ordersLists`, set it up and then add it to `arrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood from your question , I think the solution is to replace this line if your first method from

```
arrayList.add(ordersLists);
```

to

```
the name of your object that has the arrayList .setArrayList(ordersLists);
```

where the setter method `setArrayList` in this form below :

```
public void setArrayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList= arrayList;
}
```

https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices

Let me know if that helped!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you initialize `i = 0` then try to make a decrement.

But I think that you can't have an index below zero.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
         
        }
```

Try this instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){  
       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            ordersLists = new OrdersLists();
            ordersLists.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            ordersLists.setMain_cat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("main_cat"));
            ordersLists.setSub_cat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sub_cat"));
            ordersLists.setDate(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"));
            ordersLists.setPrice(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("price"));
            ordersLists.setComment(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("comment"));
            ordersLists.setCity(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("city"));
            arrayList.add(ordersLists);
        }
```